# Is there a way to ignore header lines in a UNIX sort?

Tags: unix, sorting, command-line

I have a fixed-width-field file which I'm trying to sort using the UNIX (Cygwin, in my case) sort utility.

The problem is there is a two-line header at the top of the file which is being sorted to the bottom of the file (as each header line begins with a colon).

Is there a way to tell sort either "pass the first two lines across unsorted" or to specify an ordering which sorts the colon lines to the top - the remaining lines are always start with a 6-digit numeric (which is actually the key I'm sorting on) if that helps.

Example:

```
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
222334NOTALINEOUT01
477821USASHUTTLES21
325611LVEANOTHERS00
```

should sort to:

```
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
222334NOTALINEOUT01
325611LVEANOTHERS00
477821USASHUTTLES21
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
```

Comment: For the record: the command line I'm using so far is "sort -t\\ -k1.1,1.6 <file>" [the data can contain spaces, but will never contain a backslash]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-at-the-top

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
(head -n 2 <file> && tail -n +3 <file> | sort) > newfile
```

The parentheses create a subshell, wrapping up the stdout so you can pipe it or redirect it as if it had come from a single command.

Comment: Thanks; I'm accepting this answer as it seems most complete and concise (and I understand what it's doing!) - it should be "head -n 2", though :-)

Comment: Is there a way to have this version work on piped-in data? I tried with `tee >(head -n $header_size) | tail -n +$header_size | sort`, but head seems to run after the `tail|sort` pipe, so the header ends up printed in the end. Is this deterministic or a race condition?

Comment: You could probably piece together something where you use `cat` to redirect the stdin to a temporary file, then run the above command on that new file, but it's starting to get ugly enough that it's probably better to use one of the awk-based solutions given in the other responses.

Comment: @DamienPollet: See [Dave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3398351/dave)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22281855/15168).

Comment: @DamienPollet:  See [freeseek's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4339300/freeseek) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27368739/343388)

Comment: If you're using zsh (and have `multios` set, which you should by default) you can also use `cat $file > >(head -n2) > >(tail -n+3 | sort)`.  For files it's not much of a change, but for sorting command output it has the advantage that it'll only run the command once.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work with piped in data. It seems that the tail doesn't run or gets nothing after the head. Probably because more than 1 line is being read, leaving nothing for tail.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, this is because head consumes more data than it prints, probably the first 4k block read, leaving very little data for tail. This is why the `read -r; echo "$REPLY"` solution is the correct one (i.e., never use `head` followed by `tail` on (the same) piped data!). Please upvote this comment to the top, so people don't erroneously use this (so called accepted) answer instead of the much better solution provided by freeseek's correct (for far more use cases, including piped data) answer, below.

Answer (score 124):

If you don't mind using `awk`, you can take advantage of `awk`'s built-in pipe abilities, e.g.

```bash
extract_data | awk 'NR<3{print $0;next}{print $0| "sort -r"}'
```

This prints the first two lines verbatim and pipes the rest through `sort`.

Note that this has the very specific advantage of being able to selectively sort parts
of a piped input.   all the other methods suggested will only sort plain files which can be read multiple times.  This works on anything.

Comment: Very nice, and it works with arbitrary pipes, not only files!

Comment: Beautiful, awk never stops surprising me. Also, you don't need the `$0`, `print` is enough.

Comment: @SamWatkins  [freeseek's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4339300/freeseek) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27368739/343388) is less ugly.

Comment: What's the -r option doing to sort? Is this supposed to be reverse sort?

Comment: I prefer this `awk` approach by @Dave as it works with arbitrary pipes as opposed to [@BobS 's subshell approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562674/199400) which works with files only.

Answer (score 102):

In simple cases, `sed` can do the job elegantly:

```sh
your_script | (sed -u 1q; sort)
```

or equivalently,

```sh
cat your_data | (sed -u 1q; sort)
cat your_data | { sed -u 1q; sort; }  # to avoid the subshell
```

The key is in the `1q` -- print first line (header) and quit (leaving the rest of the input to `sort`).

For the example given, `2q` will do the trick.

The `-u` switch (unbuffered) is required for those `sed`s (notably, GNU's) that would otherwise read the input in chunks, thereby consuming data that you want to go through `sort` instead.

Comment: IMO this is the simplest solution here and easiest to remember. It works with piped data with no special considerations or awkward quoting and escaping, and does not need to be used multiple times if you are sorting on multiple columns by a chain of piped sort commands with the -s flag. eg. `bgzip -dc somefile.tsv.gz | (sed -u 2q; sort -k 3,3 -n | sort -k 2,2 -n -s | sort -k 1,1 -s)  | bgzip -c > my_sorted_file.tsv.gz`. Key though is the edit adding the `-u` flag which ought to have solved @RobGilliam's problem above.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how pipe and the paenthesis work?

Comment: I would use `head -n 1` instead of `sed -u 1q`. This head command is POSIX and much more portable than dealing with sed's `-u` flag.

Comment: @dan Good idea but `head -n 1` produce a blank line after the header unlike `sed -u 1q` which doesn't have this problem, not sure why...

Comment: @dan On my system, `head` seems to be buffered like `sed`, so that doesn't work. (Ubuntu 20.04, head (GNU coreutils) 8.30)

Comment: @Gqqnbig The parentheses create a subshell. Speaking of that, you could actually use braces instead, which don't create a subshell, just a group of commands, though you'd need to add spaces plus a semicolon at the end: `... { sed -u 1q; sort; }`. The pipe works exactly like a regular pipe, but the input goes into the group of commands instead of one command.

Comment: On mac, this seems to drop some of the lines!

Answer (score 50):

Here is a version that works on piped data:

```bash
(read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort)
```

If your header has multiple lines:

```bash
(for i in $(seq $HEADER_ROWS); do read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; done; sort)
```

This solution is from [here](http://jeffgraves.me/2013/12/11/skip-header-with-bash-sort/)

Comment: nice. for the single header case I use   `extract_data | (read h; echo "$h"; sort)`  it's short enough to remember.    your example covers more edge cases. :)    This is the best answer. works on pipes.  no awk.

Comment: Ok, I straced this and it seems that bash goes to special lengths to make this work.  In general, if you coded this in C or another language it would not work because stdio would read more than just the first header line.

If you run it on a seekable file, bash reads a larger chunk (128 bytes in my test), then lseeks back to after the end of the first line.  If you run it on a pipe, bash reads one char at a time until it passes the end of the line.

Comment: Nice! If you just want to eat the header, it's even easier to remember:
`extract_data | (read; sort)`

Comment: This one is almost perfect but you need to use "IFS= read" instead of "read" to keep leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Simple, concise and more flexible in that it also works on piped data.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```bash
tail -n +3 <file> | sort ...
```

`tail` will output the file contents from the 3rd line.

Comment: But this loses the header, which is not desired.

Comment: Losing the header, but otherwise it’s the simplest and I’m most likely to remember. But I really want to print the first line (from a command’s output) then sort the rest of the output by column 6, and print that to the screen. I’ll ask that as a new question.

Comment: @OldUncleHo regarding "Losing the header, but otherwise..." - retaining the header is the only interesting thing about this question so any answer that doesn't retain the header isn't answering the question and that's why it appears to be simple, because it doesn't do the only interesting thing that the question requires of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

```sh
head -2 <your_file> && nawk 'NR>2' <your_file> | sort
```

example:

```sh
> cat temp
10
8
1
2
3
4
5
> head -2 temp && nawk 'NR>2' temp | sort -r
10
8
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 3):

It only takes 2 lines of code...

```sh
head -1 test.txt > a.tmp
tail -n+2 test.txt | sort -n >> a.tmp
```

For a numeric data, `-n` is required. For alpha sort, the `-n` is not required.

Example file:

```sh
$ cat test.txt
header
8
5
100
1
-1
```

Result:

```sh
$ cat a.tmp
header
-1
1
5
8
100
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same answer as the accepted answer? (Except BobS's approach puts the result on stdout, allowing you to send the result through other filters before being written to file, if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

So here's a bash function where arguments are exactly like sort.  Supporting files and pipes.

```bash
function skip_header_sort() {
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && [[ -f ${@: -1} ]]; then
        local file=${@: -1}
        set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
    fi
    awk -vsargs="$*" 'NR<2{print; next}{print | "sort "sargs}' $file
}
```

How it works.  This line checks if there is at least one argument and if the last argument is a file.

```bash
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && [[ -f ${@: -1} ]]; then
```

This saves the file to separate argument.  Since we're about to erase the last argument.

```bash
        local file=${@: -1}
```

Here we remove the last argument.  Since we don't want to pass it as a sort argument.

```bash
        set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
```

Finally, we do the awk part, passing the arguments (minus the last argument if it was the file) to sort in awk.  This was orignally suggested by Dave, and modified to take sort arguments.  We rely on the fact that `$file` will be empty if we're piping, thus ignored.

```bash
    awk -vsargs="$*" 'NR<2{print; next}{print | "sort "sargs}' $file
```

Example usage with a comma separated file.

```bash
$ cat /tmp/test
A,B,C
0,1,2
1,2,0
2,0,1

# SORT NUMERICALLY SECOND COLUMN
$ skip_header_sort -t, -nk2 /tmp/test
A,B,C
2,0,1
0,1,2
1,2,0

# SORT REVERSE NUMERICALLY THIRD COLUMN
$ cat /tmp/test | skip_header_sort -t, -nrk3
A,B,C
0,1,2
2,0,1
1,2,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash shell function derived from the other answers. It handles both files and pipes. First argument is the file name or '-' for stdin. Remaining arguments are passed to sort. A couple examples:

```bash
$ hsort myfile.txt
$ head -n 100 myfile.txt | hsort -
$ hsort myfile.txt -k 2,2 | head -n 20 | hsort - -r
```

The shell function:

```bash
hsort ()
{
   if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
       echo "Sort a file or standard input, treating the first line as a header.";
       echo "The first argument is the file or '-' for standard input. Additional";
       echo "arguments to sort follow the first argument, including other files.";
       echo "File syntax : $ hsort file [sort-options] [file...]";
       echo "STDIN syntax: $ hsort - [sort-options] [file...]";
       return 0;
   elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
       local file=$1;
       shift;
       (head -n 1 $file && tail -n +2 $file | sort $*);
   elif [ "$1" == "-" ]; then
       shift;
       (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort $*);
   else
       >&2 echo "Error. File not found: $1";
       >&2 echo "Use either 'hsort <file> [sort-options]' or 'hsort - [sort-options]'";
       return 1 ;
   fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Ian Sherbin answer but my implementation is :-

```bash
cut -d'|' -f3,4,7 $arg1 | uniq > filetmp.tc
head -1 filetmp.tc > file.tc;
tail -n+2 filetmp.tc | sort -t"|" -k2,2 >> file.tc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple variation on all the others, reading a file once

```bash
HEADER_LINES=2
(head -n $HEADER_LINES; sort) < data-file.dat
```

Comment: Doesn't work in a pipe. Seems like `head` is buffered, so it reads in a block just to discard most of it, and `sort` never receives that data. Use [Andrea's answer](/a/56151840/4518341) instead.

Comment: OP doesn’t mention anything about requiring pipe; use process substitution, if available ```< <(your-script)```

Comment: Process substitution does the same thing for me (running Ubuntu 20.04). I know OP didn't mention it, so I didn't downvote, just wanted to comment for the sake of anyone else using a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep

(plus cat, sort, rm)

I tested this on a MacBook Air (Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0, etc.). The script uses two working files: f1, f2. The entire input file $1 is copied to f1. From f1 the header and body lines are drawn.

Header lines contain the character ":". We grep them, and store them in f2.

The body lines do not contain the character ":", as far as we know, so we grep the remaining lines (grep -v), sort them, and append the result to f2.

Finally we cat f2 to achieve a result which can be used in a pipe line, and then we remove f1 and f2.

```
##                             ## Executable file "script"
cat $1 > f1                    ## Or cp $1 f1
grep ":" f1 > f2               ## Header lines contain ":"
grep -v ":" f1 | sort >> f2    ## Body lines do not contain ":"
cat f2                         ## List result
rm f1 f2                       ## Clean up
```

testfile:

```
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
222334NOTALINEOUT01
477821USASHUTTLES21
325611LVEANOTHERS00
```

Invoke the script as "./script testfile" (or "cat testfile | ./script > result" etc.).

```
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
222334NOTALINEOUT01
325611LVEANOTHERS00
477821USASHUTTLES21
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
```

The working files are handy for debugging, but force a clean up. I thought one would do, maybe zero, and yes, that works if you invoke it as "./script testfile". It doesn't work in a pipe, e.g. "cat testfile | ./script". You cannot rewind the standard input. But the version with two working files functions in a pipeline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Applying the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) idiom using any version of the mandatory POSIX tools `awk`, `sort`, and `cut`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), $0}' file | sort -k1 -k2 | cut -f2-
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
222334NOTALINEOUT01
325611LVEANOTHERS00
477821USASHUTTLES21
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
```

Works just fine on incoming piped input too:

```
$ cat file | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), $0}' | sort -k1 -k2 | cut -f2-
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
222334NOTALINEOUT01
325611LVEANOTHERS00
477821USASHUTTLES21
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a non-portable solution, then

```
echo '
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
222334NOTALINEOUT01
477821USASHUTTLES21
325611LVEANOTHERS00' |
```

---

```
gnu-sort -g   # -g := --general-numeric-sort   

bsd-sort -g   # -g := --general-numeric-sort
              #       --sort=general-numeric (either)
```

---

```
:0:12345
:1:6:2:3:3:8:4:2
010005TSTDOG_FOOD01
222334NOTALINEOUT01
325611LVEANOTHERS00
477821USASHUTTLES21
500123TSTMY_RADAR00
```

this assumes the header is in this exact format, and the sorting order might be different for random beyond-`ASCII` unicode headers

The `-g` flag on `bsd-sort` also worked for this input, but I don't have much insight regarding whether they're fully interchangeable for this particular flag.

Answer (score -1):

With Python:

```py
import sys
HEADER_ROWS=2

for _ in range(HEADER_ROWS):
    sys.stdout.write(next(sys.stdin))
for row in sorted(sys.stdin):
    sys.stdout.write(row)
```

Comment: pre-supposes the system has Python installed (mine doesn't)

Answer (score -7):

```
cat file_name.txt | sed 1d | sort
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: 1) This only removes the header line and sorts the rest, it doesn't sort everything below the header line leaving the header intact. 2) it removes the first line only, when the header is actually two lines (read the question). 3) Why do you use "cat file_name.txt | sed 1d" when "sed 1d < file_name.txt" or even just "sed 1d file_name.txt" has the same effect?