# Read stream and pass to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm writing a python script that reads a stream from stdin and passes this stream to `subprocess` for further processing. The problem is that python hangs after having processed the input stream.

For example, this toy program `sorter.py` should read from stdin and pass the stream to `subprocess` for sorting via Unix `sort`:

`cat dat.txt | ./sorter.py`

Here's sorter.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

p= subprocess.Popen('sort -', stdin= subprocess.PIPE, shell= True)
for line in sys.stdin:
    p.stdin.write(line)
sys.exit()
```

The stream from `cat` is correctly sorted but the programs hangs, i.e. sys.exit() is never reached.

I've read quite a few variations on this theme but I can't get it right. Any idea what is missing?

Thank you!

Dario

Comment: related: [streaming data into command with subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32662375/4279)

Answer (score 1):

My guess: `sys.exit()` is reached but `sort` continues to run. You should close `p.stdin` pipe to signal EOF to `sort`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen('sort', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
with p.stdin:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        # use line here
        p.stdin.write(line)
if p.wait() != 0:
    raise Error
```

Example:

```
$ < dat.txt ./sorter.py
```

If you don't need to modify the stdin stream then you don't need to use PIPE here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('sort')
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have a problem with buffering -the OS doesnt send the data the moment it arrives to stdin - check this out

https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering