# Sorting of data of created text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have dumped the output of a command into a text file which consists of multiple columns results in multiple rows.
The first column contains the Equipment ID and second column contain the time (In UTC)

I want to sort the rows on the basis of increasing time order(Setup time). How to do that?

Here is my command out put (dumped to a text file) :

```
Equipment ID  | Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      | End Time - GPS (UTC)
            3 | 2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC) | 2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC) | 2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC) | 2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
            3 | 2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC) | 2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
            1 | 2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC) | 2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)
```

Comment: read text from file to memory, split text in lines (`split("\n")`), split every rows into cells (`split("|")`), sort all data using second column (`sort()`, `sorted()`), write it back to file.

Comment: you could use module `pandas` and read it to DataFrame using `read_csv()` with `|` as separator. And then you can sort it in `DataFrame` and writ it back with `to_csv()`

Comment: In your scenario, what about piping the output to a .csv file instead?  Use the '|' char as its delimiter and read the file using pythons csv module.

Comment: on Linux in Bash you could do `cat example.txt | sort -k 2` but it moves header to the end. You would have to use `head`, `tail` to keep header at the top: [Is there a way to ignore header lines in a UNIX sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562423/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-header-lines-in-a-unix-sort)

Answer (score 0):

The following will load the data from file `output.txt` and print out the individual lines in order of SetupTime:

```py
import re

def collect_data(file_path):
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    data = f.read()
    collection = []
    # RegExp with Capture Group around(0: The Whole Line, 1: Equipment ID, 2: SetupTime)
    data_rows = re.findall('((\d+) \| \d+ \((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}) UTC\) \| \d+ \(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3} UTC\))', data)
    for row in data_rows:
        collection.append(
            {
                'EquipmentId': row[1],
                'SetupTime': row[2],
                'Line': row[0]
            }
        )
    return collection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    collection = collect_data('output.txt')
    newlist = sorted(collection, key=lambda k: k['SetupTime'])
    for item in newlist:
        print(item['Line'])
```

## Output:

```
3 | 2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC) | 2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
2 | 2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC) | 2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
3 | 2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC) | 2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
1 | 2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC) | 2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)
2 | 2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC) | 2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame` from module `pandas` and read it as csv with separator `|`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='|', dtype=str)
df = df.sort_values(' Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      ')
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

Because `read_csv()` tries to convert values to numbers so I use `dtype=str` to keep all as strings.

I keeps all spaces in values and column's names so later I can write it back formated as before. But I have to also use spaces in name `' Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      '` to sort it

Because `DataFrame` adds index to every row so I have to skip indexes in `to_csv()`

---

**EDIT:** Example using `io.StringIO` to read data from memory instead of file so everyone can easily test it without saving data in file.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data ='''Equipment ID  | Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      | End Time - GPS (UTC)
            3 | 2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC) | 2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC) | 2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC) | 2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
            3 | 2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC) | 2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
            1 | 2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC) | 2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)'''

#file_ = "data.txt"
file_ = io.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(file_, sep='|', dtype=str)
df = df.sort_values(' Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      ')
#df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', index=False)

pd.options.display.width = 150
pd.options.display.max_columns = 5
print(df)
```

Result in `DataFrame`:

```
   Equipment ID     Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                                                End Time - GPS (UTC)
3              3    2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC)    2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
1              2    2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC)    2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
0              3    2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC)    2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
4              1    2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC)    2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)
2              2    2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC)    2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not too long, I would simply use `split()`, `sorted()`, and nothing else.

```
txt = '''
Equipment ID  | Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      | End Time - GPS (UTC)
            3 | 2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC) | 2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC) | 2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC) | 2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
            3 | 2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC) | 2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
            1 | 2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC) | 2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)
'''

lines = []
for line in txt.split('\n'):
    if len(line):
        lines.append(line.split('('))

#Separate the header from the rest,
#and sort the entries based on the Setup Time
header, lines = lines[0], sorted(lines[1:], key=lambda x: x[1])

#write back the sorted text
sorted_txt = '('.join(header)
for line in lines:
    sorted_txt += '\n' + '('.join(line)
```

The output of `print(sorted_txt)`:

```
Equipment ID  | Setup Time - GPS (UTC)                      | End Time - GPS (UTC)
            3 | 2068506038500 (2019-08-30 20:33:40.500 UTC) | 2068506399300 (2019-08-30 20:39:41.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068506579500 (2019-08-30 20:42:41.500 UTC) | 2068507041300 (2019-08-30 20:50:23.300 UTC)
            3 | 2068512564500 (2019-08-30 22:22:26.500 UTC) | 2068513054300 (2019-08-30 22:30:36.300 UTC)
            1 | 2068512827500 (2019-08-30 22:26:49.500 UTC) | 2068512852300 (2019-08-30 22:27:14.300 UTC)
            2 | 2068513133500 (2019-08-30 22:31:55.500 UTC) | 2068513614300 (2019-08-30 22:39:56.300 UTC)
```

You can write the output on a file, of course.

If your file is very long or if you need to repeat this computation over and over in production, then go for Pandas as suggested by @furas.