# Sort lines between two patterns in file recursively

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have file with following format

```
3
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:
1 1 -0.00119157 -5.67557e-05 -1.49279e-04
2 3 0.00220589 -0.00133867 9.67397e-04
3 2 -5.43822e-04 -0.00119676 -8.99064e-05
3
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:
1 1 -0.00119157 -5.67557e-05 -1.49279e-04
2 3 0.00220589 -0.00133867 9.67397e-04
3 2 -5.43822e-04 -0.00119676 -8.99064e-05
```

I would like to be able to sort the content of the file according to the second column without modifing the lines analog to the following that should always stay in place

```
3
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:
```

Expected output

```
3
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:
1 1 -0.00119157 -5.67557e-05 -1.49279e-04
3 2 -5.43822e-04 -0.00119676 -8.99064e-05
2 3 0.00220589 -0.00133867 9.67397e-04
3
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:
1 1 -0.00119157 -5.67557e-05 -1.49279e-04
3 2 -5.43822e-04 -0.00119676 -8.99064e-05
2 3 0.00220589 -0.00133867 9.67397e-04
```

I tried [Is there a way to ignore header lines in a UNIX sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562423/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-header-lines-in-a-unix-sort)
but didn't worked out as expected.

I would like to this in BASH.

Comment: Please do mention your sample of expected output in your question. Also keep the samples of input and output clear and short(in length) in your question.

Comment: Actually, you might want to change the title of your question to _Sort lines between two patterns in file_. Also, your question is very poorly defined. Your expected output is not sorted according to the first and second column at all.

Comment: The expected output looks like it's sorted by the *third* column. Are those lines from the entire input file, or just the lines between two "lattice" lines?

Comment: @tripleee yeah those sorted lines from entire set of 1080 lines after the header. I can't paste all those here.

Comment: @EdMorton there are 1080 lines between the pattern of "1080 'Lattice' ..."

Comment: That doesn't clarify much. Do you mean there are 1800 lines in each section and you want to sort each section on the third column (not the first and second)?

Comment: @tripleee there are 1080 lines after ``` 1080 Lattice ``` part and with repeating same pattern.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many lines are present in your real data, you need to come up with a [mcve] that represents your problem in a minimal way (e.g. 5 lines instead of 1800 lines) for us to be able to help you. See [ask].

Comment: Are the "dots" `...` just a way to show that there are more data or are thy really there?

Comment: Is that `1080` the number of expected lines in the next chunk?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia yeah there is more data means "dots". Yes expected chunk is 1080 excluding `1080
Lattice="89.8218778092 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.8543061924 0.0 0.0 0.0 25.203816" Properties=id:I:1:species:S:1:`

Answer (score 1):

This is moderately tricky in Bash or with traditional line-oriented Unix utilities, but almost easy in GNU Awk or a modern scripting language like Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

section = []
lattice = False

def sort_em(lines):
    return ''.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda x: tuple(map(float, x.split()[2:4]))))

def print_em(*lines):
    print(*lines, end='')

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('1080\n'):
        if section:
            print_em(sort_em(section))
            section = []
        lattice = True
        print_em(line)
    elif lattice:
        if not line.startswith('Lattice="'):
            raise ValueError('Expected Lattice="..." but got %s' % line)
        lattice = False
        print_em(line)
    else:
        section.append(line)
if section:
    print_em(sort_em(section))
```

You would save this in a file in your `PATH`, and `chmod a+x` it. If you called it `sortsections`, you would run it like

```sh
sortsections filename >newfile
```

to read the lines in `filename` and output them to `newfile` sorted as per the requirements.

Demo: https://ideone.com/7RRvXQ

The `tuple(map(float ...))` thing extracts the fields we want to sort on, converts them all to `float`, and collects them into a `tuple`. (Slightly obscurely, `map` returns a generator object so we have to generate the result by calling `tuple()` on it.)  The `print` wrapper avoids having to repeat `end=''` every time we want to print something. (The lines we read each have a trailing newline already, but `print` without `end=''` would add another.)

This hard-codes `1080` as the marker of a new section; it would not be hard to change it to read the first line and then use that as the marker for all subsequent sections, and/or count that each section contains that many lines, and read a new count when you have consumed the number of lines indicated in each header section.

Comment: The question is about a bash solution...

Comment: Is there any way to invoke sort after extracting pattern by awk recursively?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia It could be done in Bash (see other answer now) but one of the skills you need as a shell programmer is when to know when to shift to a language where the solution comes naturally. Traditionally you would have to learn `sed` and Awk as well as shell, but in this day and age, for this particular solution, I chose Python, which is very widely available on a large number of platforms. (Bonus: it runs on Windows too, if you are of a masochistic bent.)

Comment: @abhijitdhakane It's not impossible, but the problem with an Awk solution is that it would have to rely on an external `sort`. Python has `sorted` built in so the solution is obvious and straightforward. (The main wart is how I had to wrap `print` to avoid writing a second newline. I guess I could have used `write` instead.)

Comment: @tripleee did you see my solution below? It is probably slower than your (since it is about creating many files) but I used it many times in the past and is quite faster to write...

Comment: It's not like I spent a lot of time on this one either.  Maybe 5 minutes to write and 15 to polish it (took longer than usual because I renamed a variable but forgot to change it in one place).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to split the big file you have in many smaller file containing only 1 cell. Then you use the method you also linked to sort the lines the way you want in each file. Finally you concatenate the files with the sorted data together with `cat`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nlines=$(head -n 1 $1)     # Get the number of lines per each cell
let nlines+=2              # Add to the number of sites the header lines
split -l $nlines -a 5 $1   # Split the file in multiple files each one containing a single cell
for file in ${1}*; do      # Sort each file individually
  (head -n 2 $file && tail -n +3 $file | sort -k 2) > sorted-$file;
cat sorted-${1}* > $2      # Concatenate all the sorted files
rm sorted-${1}*            # Remove the sorted files
```

Use this as:

```
script.sh <file_name> <new_file_name>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I did not test this, try it in a clean folder with a copy of the original file. This is going to generate many files and clean them at the end.

If you provide a real example on pastylink for example, I can twik the script better.

Comment: @abhijit dhakane let me know if this worked... :)

Comment: Probably [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable); it would be silly for this to break just because the user passed in a file name which contains spaces or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: A proper solution would use `mktemp -d` to create a directory for the temporary files, and a `trap` to remove the temporary directory in the case of an error or SIGTERM.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah... the `mktemp` + `trap` is a very nice idea! Most of the time I write this kind of scripts for a single usage... so do not spend too much time in improving them... but next time will try with your suggestions! tyty