# How do pipes inside awk work (Sort with keeping header)

Tags: shell, awk

The following command outputs the header of a file and sorts the records after the header. But how does it work? Can anyone explain this command?

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -k3"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please go through following once(only for explanation purposes). For learning more concepts on `awk` I suggest go through [Stack overflow's nice awk learning section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program from here.
NR == 1;                 ##Checking if line is first line then print it.
##awk works on method of condition then action since here is NO ACTION mentioned so by default printing of current line will happen
NR > 1{                  ##If line is more than 1st line then do following.
 print $0 | "sort -k3"   ##It will be keep printing lines into memory and before printing it will sort them with their 3rd field.
}'
```

Comment: after NR == 1 there is no {print}, is it printing the record by default

Comment: @VipulBajaj, yes `awk` works on method of `condition` then `action` since here is NO ACTION mentioned so by default printing of current line will happen, cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt and clear explanation

Comment: @VipulBajaj, Your welcome and happy learning on SO.

Comment: Good use of shell command piped inside `awk`

Answer (score 2):

**Understanding the awk command:**
Overall an awk program is build out of `(pattern){action}` pairs which stat that if `pattern` returns a non-zero value, `action` is executed. One does not necessarily, need to write both. If `pattern` is omitted, it defaults to `1` and if `action` is omitted, it defaults to `print $0`.

When looking at the command in question:

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -k3"}'
```

We notice that there are two action-pattern pairs. The first reads `NR == 1` and states that if we are processing the first record (pattern) then print the record (default action). The second is a bit more tricky. The pattern is clear, the action on the other hand needs some explaining.

awk has knowledge of 4 output statements that can redirect the output. One of these reads `expression  | cmd` . It essentially means that awk will write output to a stream that is piped as input to a command `cmd`. It will keep on writing the output to that stream until the stream is explicitly closed using a `close(cmd)` statement or by simply terminating awk.

In case of the OP, the action reads `{ print $0 | "sort -k3" }`, meaning that it will print all records `$0` to a stream that is used as input of the shell command `sort -k3`. Only when the program finishes will `sort` write its output.

> **Recap:** the command of the OP will print the first line of a file, and sort the consecutive lines according the third column.

**Alternative solutions:**

Using GNU awk, it is better to do:

```
awk '(FNR==1);{a[$3]=$0}
     END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
        for(i in a) print a[i]
     }' file
```

Using pure shell, it is better to do:

```
cat file | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k3)
```

**Related questions:**

- [Is there a way to ignore header lines in a UNIX sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562423/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-header-lines-in-a-unix-sort)

Answer (score 0):

`|` is one of [redirections supported by print and printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) - in this case pipe to command `sort -k3`. You might also use redirection to write to file using `>`:

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 > "output.txt"}'
```

or append to file using `>>`:

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 >> "output.txt"}'
```

First will write to file `output.txt` all lines but first, second will append to `output.txt` all lines but first.