# How to merge two .txt file in unix based on one common column. Unix

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk, merge

I have two .txt files. File1.txt and File2.txt. How can i merge these two files in unix (may be with awk) based on one common column.

`File1.txt` looks like

```
Sub_ID  Sam_ID   v1              
1878372 2253734 SAMN06396112           
1883177 2264293 SAMN06414028          
1884646 2275341 SAMN06432785         
1860945 2277481 SAMN06407597
```

`File2.txt` looks like

```
Sam_ID  code    V3      V4 
2253734 20481   NA      DNA   
2275341 20483   NA      DNA    
2277481 20488   NA      DNA
```

Final output file after merging should look like this

```
Finalfile.txt

Sub_ID  Sam_ID   v1               code   V3      V4
1878372 2253734 SAMN06396112     20481   NA      DNA                
1884646 2275341 SAMN06432785     20483   NA      DNA     
1860945 2277481 SAMN06407597     20488   NA      DNA
```

I have tried  Join so far but may be i am not fully understanding the command (being new to unix).

```
sort -k2b File1.txt >sorted_file1.txt 
sort File2.txt >sorted_file2.txt 
join -1 2 sorted_file1.txt sorted_file2.txt > Finalfile.txt
```

I understand that by k2b i am nominating the second column of File_1 to be common among two and then merging.

Comment: Could you please show us any attempt from your side?

Comment: You could use programming language that has support for relational db and use it to create an SQLite database and then execute a join between your two "tables" and produce the output you want.

Comment: What's your field separator in both files? One tab or multiple spaces?

Comment: One tab. @Cyrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for adding your own attempts to solve the problem - it makes troubleshooting a lot easier.

This answer is a bit convoluted, but here is a potential solution (GNU join):

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 <(head -n 1 File1.txt && tail -n +2 File1.txt | sort -k2,2 ) <(head -n 1 File2.txt && tail -n +2 File2.txt | sort -k1,1)

#Sam_ID Sub_ID  v1  code    V3  V4
#2253734    1878372 SAMN06396112    20481   NA  DNA
#2275341    1884646 SAMN06432785    20483   NA  DNA
#2277481    1860945 SAMN06407597    20488   NA  DNA
```

Explanation:

- join uses a single character as a separator, so you can't use `"\t"`, but you can use `$'\t'` (as far as I know)
- the `-1 2` and `-2 1` means "for the first file, use the second field" and "for the second file, use the first field" when combining the files
- in each subprocess (`<()`), sort the file by the Sam_ID column but exclude the header from the sort (per [Is there a way to ignore header lines in a UNIX sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562423/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-header-lines-in-a-unix-sort))

### Edit

To specify the order of the columns in the output (to put the Sub_ID before the Sam_ID), you can use the `-o` option, e.g.

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(head -n 1 File1.txt && tail -n +2 File1.txt | sort -k2,2 ) <(head -n 1 File2.txt && tail -n +2 File2.txt | sort -k1,1)

#Sub_ID Sam_ID  v1  code    V3  V4
#1878372    2253734 SAMN06396112    20481   NA  DNA
#1884646    2275341 SAMN06432785    20483   NA  DNA
#1860945    2277481 SAMN06407597    20488   NA  DNA
```

Comment: Hi Jared: Thanks but the only problem i am facing with my attempt is the headers are removed. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: In my example the headers from each file are retained. Are you sure they are separated by a single tab?

Answer (score 2):

This single `awk` should work file for merge task:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$2] = $0; next} {print map[$1], $0}' File1.txt File2.txt | column -t

Sub_ID   Sam_ID   v1            Sam_ID   code   V3  V4
1878372  2253734  SAMN06396112  2253734  20481  NA  DNA
1884646  2275341  SAMN06432785  2275341  20483  NA  DNA
1860945  2277481  SAMN06407597  2277481  20488  NA  DNA
```

`column -t` has been used for tabular output only.

PS: If first column from File2 is not found in File1 then you will get a leading space in output.

Answer (score 1):

With `cut` `grep` and `pr` and ProcSub from `bash`.

```
pr -mt <(grep -Fv 1883177 file1.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file2.txt)
```

---

Output

```
Sub_ID  Sam_ID   v1                  code    V3      V4
1878372 2253734 SAMN06396112        20481   NA      DNA
1884646 2275341 SAMN06432785        20483   NA      DNA
1860945 2277481 SAMN06407597        20488   NA      DNA
```

---

Or `paste`

```
paste -d' ' <(grep -Fv 1883177 file1.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file2.txt) | column -t > Finalfile.txt
```